# How to find out where CNAME had resolved to in the past?

Tags: dns

Are there any tools for this?

I am doing some research into pentesting and subdomain takeovers with cloud providers like AWS and Azure. I have a list of subdomains (A records) that could be used for this, but they are indecipherable in terms of seeing where they once resolved to. Without this information, the entire thing is redundant.

For example:

`sjd-3949-af3.trafficmanager.net` would have originally resolved to `mydomain.takeover.com` but doesn't now.

Does anyone know how to find this out?

Comment: There's no standard way. The best you could do is look for websites that index DNS entries and save historical versions, but this has little coverage and no guarantees whatsoever. Search for something like "historical dns data".

Comment: @Marc I wondered about using [EyeWitness](https://github.com/FortyNorthSecurity/EyeWitness) for capturing screenshots but this seems a bit OTT long-term.

Comment: Have you looked into "passive DNS" tools? I'm not sure if it includes the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

DNS does not provide historical records. So unless it's been cached somewhere public in a way that you can access it, there is no way to know what a CNAME resolved to.

Comment: You are describing "passive DNS" tools

Comment: Didn't know about it, looking into the repo now.

Comment: Though this type of tool needs to be used proactively, considering that you *might* need the records.

Comment: Some places store the records indefinitely. Mostly paid repos, though.

Comment: What do you mean "most places"? Are you referring to ISPs? Cloud providers? If yes, then you may be right in some cases, but the likelihood of someone else being able to see those records is slim to none. Specialised DNS tracking products would only ever be able to cover a limited amount of names over time.

Comment: Most "Passive DNS" providers: https://www.circl.lu/services/passive-dns/

Answer (score 1):

Rapid7's [Project Sonar](https://opendata.rapid7.com/) periodically saves snapshots of Internet-wide DNS records. Access to historical datasets is a paid feature, but it would allow you to go back in time and figure out where a given host pointed at a given time.